# QMediaPlayer doesn't change status at the end of file

Tags: macos, qt, video, qt5, eof

I'm using Qt 5.1 (from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0/qt-mac-opensource-5.1.0-clang-offline.dmg)) on a MacBook Pro (OSX 10.8.4).

I have a movie player application consisting of little more than a `QMediaPlayer` and a `QVideoWidget`.  Video from a local file URL plays fine.

I can connect and monitor the player's `mediaStatusChanged` and `positionChanged` signals, and increase the rate at which they're reported with `QMediaPlayer::setNotifyInterval` to several times per second.

This all seems to work fine except for one annoying thing:

When the player reaches the end of the file, it doesn't change status, it just reports the same position repeatedly.  Only (and this is where things get strange) if I resize the window or minimise/maximise it, does it seem to "flush out" the expected status change to `QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia`.  Even just raising another application to cover the video app seems to flush the status change.

Any suggestions?  Bug in `QMediaPlayer`?  Me doing something wrong?  Suggestions for workrounds?

**Update:** Now [reported in Qt Jira](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33761).